# Facebook Oauth Code Flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/

On this page, there is a video that talks about security issues related to Facebook login. Around 13 minutes, he talks about oauth code flow. The idea is that if you're only making requests from the server, you should generate a code that you can then trade for an access token on the server.

To do this, you set response_type to code in the query params.

[image: response_type code]

My question is how do you do that with the SDKs? The video suggests that you need to set Client Oath Login to false in the settings:

[image: settings]

I did that, but I can see in the Chrome network tab that the SDK is still setting response_type to token. The result is this error:

[image: error]

What am I missing?

TL;DR I want to use the Facebook login dialog to get an access code that I can trade for an access token on the server.

Comment: You don’t do that with the JS SDK, because with the JS SDK you always have a client-side token. Depending on what SDK you are using, it should probably already have methods on board to handle the login flow as it is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: @CBroe Can you use code flow with the iOS or Android SDKs? Or is only if  you're manually building a login flow?